# Are there any other way to decrease inference time?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, huggingface-transformers, pre-trained-model

I am using a pre-trained model from huggingface to do sentiment analysis on my twitter dataset which has 1.5 million tweets. I load the model by using

```
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("savasy/bert-base-turkish-sentiment-cased")
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("savasy/bert-base-turkish-sentiment-cased")
sa= pipeline("sentiment-analysis", tokenizer=tokenizer, model=model, device=0)
```

so i am using my gpu (rtx 2060). I did some tests to estimate the time it will took to do inference in 1.5 million tweets and it approximately takes 5 hours. I estimated this by observing the time it took with given sizes. And it looks like it increases linearly.

```
size: 10 , 0.2910006046295166 seconds
size: 100 , 1.1989195346832275 seconds
size: 1000 , 12.097795724868774 seconds
size: 10000 , 123.63561415672302 seconds
```

Is there any other way to decrease inference time or should i just run code for 5 hours ?

Edit:
I also observed that the gpu utilization is at max %30

The model i use https://huggingface.co/savasy/bert-base-turkish-sentiment-cased

Answer (score 0):

If the dataset you're trying to use is definitely large, if you want to decrease the loading time after loading you may decrease the timings between data **preparation and training** phase, but the problem is you just loaded the dataset to the project, may be trying using the dataset in cache memory which can decrease the inference time bit lower,